# What is the difference between ThreadContext.put() and MDC.Put()?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, thread-safety, log4j2

I just want  to  know the difference between threadContext.put and MDC.put.Because, i believe that both are doing the same operation.

Answer (score 9):

> Log4j 2 continues with the idea of the **MDC** and the **NDC** but
>   merges them into a single **Thread Context**. The Thread Context Map is
>   the equivalent of the MDC and the Thread Context Stack is the
>   equivalent of the NDC. Although these are frequently used for purposes
>   other than diagnosing problems, they are still frequently referred to
>   as the **MDC** and **NDC** in Log4j 2 since they are already well known by
>   those **acronyms**.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

Comment: which means  leveraging the threadcontext is the ideal one right

Comment: Yes. as per the code MDC is just a layer over ThreadContext - https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-1.2-api/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/MDC.java

Comment: Also if was able to answer your question don't forget to upvote / accept my ans :)

Comment: sure @saurav. If you feel the question make sense..You can also upvote it.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html):

> org.apache.log4j.MDC and org.apache.log4j.NDC have been replaced by the Thread Context.